# Xamarin Forms: Show an entrybox after tapping an image

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, layer, xamarin.forms.entry

I am trying to show an entrybox after tapping an image.

I have this:

[image]

And I want to achieve this after tapping on the keyboard image:

[image]

The gesture is not a problem I add this lines:

```
    keyboard.GestureRecognizer.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer((view,args) =>
    {
            ShowEntryBox();
    })):
```

The problem is that I do not know how I can show the entry box, I use XAML. I tried relativelayout and I saw samples of absolutelayout but I can not achieve it.

I am using Xamarin forms to android and ios App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps try a **Grid**?

In the *center cell* you can create two child controls:-

*) **Label** control.

*) **Entry** control.

and then give these controls each a *name* and set the appropriate **.IsVisible** value on each of these two controls accordingly, or alternatively hook the *IsVisible* for each of these controls into a *ViewModel* and set the state there instead.

Comment: I did not use a gridlayout... I am going to try it. Thanks for the idea. I will post my advances